# How to build an external linux module which uses a custom library

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to compile an external linux driver with the the line below within an existing platform using many dependencies (such as libraries):

```
    obj-m += mydriver.o
    KDIR ?= $(OUT_DIR)
    default:
       $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD
    clean:
       $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD clean
    modules:
       $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD modules
```

I have noticed that this invokes the kernel Makefile with creates object files and does the link in order to prepare a "module".ko loadable with linux. But what if, I have to use a specific library (eg. my_library.a): how can I prevent the Linux makefile to take into account this extra library when linking all the object files

```
   Appendice:
```

My_library.a is a c++ source code contains functions that access to FPGA registers in order to report some useful data. Then my_driver (since it is a C code source , I had to create an C- interface from my_library.a ) will prepare basic system calls accessible from a user-space application. Bottom of line, my_driver reads from FPGA with 8khz, thanks to my_library.a via a C-interface and make data readable for user-space APP.

Cheers,
sahbi

Comment: What *exactly* is your `my_library.a`? Please edit your question to improve it and be specific.

Comment: And what exactly is your module doing? What kind of driver are you developping?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing concepts of user-space drivers versus kernel space ones.

Comment: I am talking about out-of-tree modules

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you cannot use an application-level external library `libmy.a` or `my_library.a` in any kernel module (or kernel code). Such libraries are generally built above the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (e.g. because they use `<stdio.h>` thru `fprintf` or `<stdlib.h>` thru `malloc`), which does not exist for kernel code.

Conceptually kernel modules and kernel code is *freestanding* (i.e. not above the C standard library).

Notice that the ABI & calling conventions might be different in kernel code and in application code. And certainly, some standard functions (like `malloc`, `printf`, `snprintf` ....) might not exist inside the kernel. BTW kernel code is not allowed to use floating point, etc...

Of course, you could link *your own* kernel library (out of your own kernel object files), but that is often not worthwhile.

<sup>(an improbable exception could be some external library which do not use any standard C function and do not compute with floating point, but that does not happen in pracice)</sup>

At last, the conventional wisdom is to avoid needing lot of kernel code. So you should consider having some helper user-mode process. See [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html).

You probably should redesign your driver to avoid needing any external library. Since you read the FPGA at only 8KHz, that part of your code could sit in user-land above existing system calls.

Notice that kernel code cannot be written in C++